# PHP error: Uninitialized string offset: 0 when I try to add multiple rows by one click in to one column using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

These are the my requirements

1. there is a form with several rows and submit button
2. I want to save that all rows in form just click a button once
3. data should be saved using one primary key and foreign key
4. I want to save the total and grand total also.how to do that

When I insert it in to input fields jQuery doesn't work.

For example:

```
id user quantity unit
1    1   10      kg
         5      kg
         3      kg
2        8      cube
         1      kg
```

I tried to using below code for inset multiple data at one (nu2 in requirement list) but I get

> PHP ERROR : unitialized string offset: 0

Can anyone please help me to fix my problem?

**view**

```
        <?php include 'header.php'; ?>


    <div class="row clear_fix" style="width:1990px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div id="response"></div>

            <div class="well">

<form class="form-inline" role="form" id="frmadd" action="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/boq_controller/create" method="POST">

        <table class="table" id="boq_tbl">
        <thead>

          <th>Work Product Id</th> 
          <th>Cost Code</th>
          <th>Work Item Description</th> 
          <th>Quentity</th>
          <th>Unit</th>
          <th>Laboure-Hrs</th>
          <th>Labour Cost</th> 
          <th>Others</th>
          <th>Total</th>

       <thead>

            <tbody>
    <tr class="txtMult">

        <td><input type="text" name="work_product_id" class="form-control" id="work_product_id" placeholder=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cost_code" class="form-control" id="cost_code" placeholder=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="work_item_description" class="form-control" id="work_item_description" placeholder=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="quentity" id="" class="form-control val1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="unit" class="form-control val2"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="laboure_hrs" id="" class="form-control val3" /></td>
        <td><input type="text"name="laboure_cost" id="" class="form-control val4"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="others" class="form-control" id="others" placeholder=""></td>


        <td>
                <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

     </tbody>
       </table> 
<p align="right">
    Grand Total# <span id="grandTotal">0.00</span>
    <button id="insert-more" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>

</p>

<div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn btn-success" value="submit">
                </div>

</form>
  </div>

  </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$("#insert-more").click(function () {
     $("#boq_tbl").each(function () {
         var tds = '<tr class="txtMult">';
         jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
             tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
         });
         tds += '</tr>';
         if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
             $('tbody', this).append(tds);
         } else {
             $(this).append(tds);
         }
     });
});

$("#boq_tbl").on("keyup", ".txtMult input", multInputs);

function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    // for each row:
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {

        console.log('---dkhal');
        // get the values from this row:
        var val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
        var val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
        var val3 = $('.val3', this).val();
        var val4 = $('.val4', this).val();
        var total = (val1 * val2 ) + (val3 * val4);

        console.log('---'+val1 * val2);
        $('.multTotal',this).text(total);
        mult += total;
    });
    $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Boq_controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
//        $this->load->model('boq_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

public function index(){

    $this->load->view('admin_include/header');
    $this->load->view('project/boq');

}
public function create(){

    if ($_POST) 
    {
        $work_product_id=$this->input->post('work_product_id');
        $work_item_description=$this->input->post('work_item_description');
        $quentity=$this->input->post('quentity');
        $unit=$this->input->post('unit');
        $laboure_hrs=$this->input->post('laboure_hrs');
        $laboure_cost=$this->input->post('laboure_cost');
        $others=$this->input->post('others');

        $data = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->input->post('id')); $i++)
        {
            $data[$i] = array(
                'work_product_id' => $id[$i],
                'work_item_description' => $work_item_description[$i],
                'quentity' => $quentity[$i],
                'unit' => $unit[$i],
                'laboure_hrs' => $laboure_hrs[$i],
                'laboure_cost' =>$laboure_cost[$i],
                'others' =>$others[$i]

            );
        }
        $this->boq_model->create($data);
    }

}

}
```

**model**

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Boq_model extends CI_Controller{

function create($data) {
    $this->db->insert_batch('quotation', $data);
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Try to check your variable by using `if(isset($YOURVARIABLE))`

Comment: any one can help me to insert <span class="multTotal">0.00</span> , and <p align="right">
    Grand Total# <span id="grandTotal">0.00</span>
    <button id="insert-more" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
</p>  into input field